# Changing a long imperative block of code into a more functional programming style

Tags: functional-programming

I am new to functional programming and I want to learn how to structure my programs by composing functions (so that I can choose which ones to use a-la-carte based on my needs)

I have a long block of imperative code that goes like this in pseudo-code:

```
function do_complicated_stuff(input) {
    //do some DB stuff and get information about A,B,C,D
    //prepare Output A
    //prepare Output B
    //prepare Output C
    //prepare Output D
    if(condition) {
       A = "I am A1"
       B = "I am B1"
       C = "I am C1"
       D = "I am D1"
    } else {
       //do the same as above, but change to I am A2, B2, C2, D2
    }
    array = {A, B, C, D};
    return array;
}
```

Is there a way to write this as function application instead of imperative code? Things I want to simplify: I don't want to handle A, B, C, D explicitly so I don't want to make function calls like do_other_stuff(A, B, C, D, db_stuff_required_for_A, db_stuff_required_for_B)

So clearly I want to have a function like `do_other_stuff(one_item)`, but the eventual return value should be something like "I am A1" if `one_item` is `A` and `condition` is true and "I am B2" if `condition` is false and `one_item` is `B`.

I know how I would do this in an OOP way, I guess I'd have a bunch of objects that know what to do with their own data where I just need to call item.other_stuff() and it figures it out. How would I write the same thing in a more functional style, composing many short functions that do one thing to give me the desired "I am L#" result in the end? Note that you need different DB information for each of the eight cases that sometimes overlaps and is sometimes completely different between each case. So it's currently very complected and not very simple, since the function in my current code is over 100 lines and handles all eight cases explicitly. Worse, the same thing is done again in a different way with a different output format like "This is A1" somewhere else. So I'd like to separate the output from the processing and from the DB calls. Let's assume I could pick any language to re-implement this in, so take any functional feature you want. How would I do this and which abstractions/language features do I need?

Brace yourself, this is the ACTUAL php code and it's not pretty and handles only half of the cases (but I want to extend it to cover everything, of course, instead of using the old code)

```
function do_complicated_stuff(Buysellitem $item) {
    $result = new stdClass();

    global $user_currency;
    $curr_obj = get_cached('getCurrenciesDAO', 'load', array($item->currencyID));
    $price = CurrencyConverter::convert($curr_obj->abbr, $user_currency->abbr, $item->price);
    $dollarPrice = CurrencyConverter::convert($curr_obj->abbr, 'USD', $item->price);

    $item_cat_id = $item->categoryId;
    if(!empty($item_cat_id)) {
        $item_cat = DAOFactory::getCategoryDetailsDAO()->load($item_cat_id)->categoryNameEn;
    }

    $designer_obj = DAOFactory::getUsersDAO()->load($item->userID);

    $item_images = DAOFactory::getBuysellitemimagesDAO()->queryByBuySellID($item->buySellID);
    foreach($item_images as $cur_image) {
        if($cur_image->isDefault) {
            if(!empty($cur_image->aspectRatio) && $cur_image->aspectRatio > 0){
                $main_image_height = round(498 / $cur_image->aspectRatio);
                $main_image =  DOMAIN . SELLIMG_PATH .
                    File_Controller::getImage($cur_image->buySellItemImagePath, 498, $main_image_height);
            }else{
                $main_image = '';
            }
        }
    }

    $designerName = decode_entities($designer_obj->companyName);
    $trim_cat = !empty($item_cat) ? ' #' . strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $item_cat)) : '';
    $desc = decode_entities($item->description);
    $trim_desc = str_short($desc, SHARE_LENGTH);
    $item_link = SHARE_ITEM_LINK . $item->buySellID;
    $item_name = str_short(decode_entities($item->buySellName), TW_SHARE);

    if(!empty($price)) {
        $decimals = $price < 10 ? 2 : 0;
        $dollarDecimals = $price < 10 ? 2 : 0;
        $priceFormatted = number_format($price, $decimals, '.', '');
        $dollarPriceFormatted = number_format($dollarPrice, $dollarDecimals, '.', '');

        //if the currency is SEK it doesn't have a sign, so show the abbreviation instead
        $curr_abbr = empty($curr_obj->sign) ? $curr_obj->abbr : '';

        $price_tag = ($item->discount > 0) ?
            ", at {$item->discount}% off":
            " - {$curr_obj->sign}$priceFormatted$curr_abbr";

        $d_price_tag = ($item->discount > 0) ?
            ", at {$item->discount}% off":
            " - \$$dollarPriceFormatted";
    } else {
        $price_tag = '';
        $d_price_tag = '';
    }

    $text = "{$item_name}$price_tag by $designerName";
    $pi_html = "$item_link \n {$item_name}$d_price_tag by $designerName \n $trim_desc";
    $tw_text = "$text$trim_cat #design";
    $tu_html = "<a href='$item_link'><strong>$text</strong></a><br/>$desc";

    $result->facebook = new stdClass();
    $result->twitter = new stdClass();
    $result->tumblr = new stdClass();
    $result->pinterest = new stdClass();

    if(empty($item->video)) {
        $result->facebook->link = FB_LINK . '?' . http_build_query(array(
                'u'=>$item_link,
                'display'=>'popup',
                'redirect_uri'=>FACEBOOK_TRACK
            ), '', '&amp;');
        $result->twitter->link = TW_LINK . '?' . http_build_query(array(
                'original_referrer'=> DOMAIN . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
                'url'=>$item_link,
                'related'=>'CityBlis',
                'via'=>'CityBlis',
                'text'=>$tw_text
            ), '', '&amp;');
        $result->tumblr->link = TU_LINK . '?' . http_build_query(array(
                'source'=>$main_image,
                'caption'=>$tu_html,
                'clickthru'=> $item_link
            ), '', '&amp;');
        $result->pinterest->link = PI_LINK . '?' . http_build_query(array(
                'url'=>$item_link,
                'media'=>$main_image,
                'description'=>$pi_html
            ), '', '&amp;');
    } else {
        $video_link = youtube_vimeo($item->video);

        $result->facebook->link = FB_LINK . '?' . http_build_query(array(
                'link'=>$item_link,
                'display'=>'popup',
                'source'=>$video_link,
                'picture'=>$main_image,
                'redirect_uri'=>FACEBOOK_TRACK
            ), '', '&amp;');
        $result->twitter->link = TW_LINK . '?' . http_build_query(array(
                'original_referrer'=> DOMAIN . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
                'url'=>$item_link,
                'related'=>'CityBlis',
                'via'=>'CityBlis',
                'text'=>$tw_text
            ), '', '&amp;');
        $result->tumblr->link = TU_LINK . '?' . http_build_query(array(
                'embed'=>$video_link,
                'caption'=>$tu_html
            ), '', '&amp;');
        $result->pinterest->link = PI_LINK . '?' . http_build_query(array(
                'url'=>$video_link,
                'media'=>$main_image,
                'description'=>$pi_html,
                'is_video'=>'true'
            ), '', '&amp;');
    }

    return $result;
}

function inline_product_share($input) {

    $item = do_complicated_stuff($input);
    $item->facebook->title = FB_TITLE;
    $item->facebook->innerStyle = '';
    $item->facebook->dimensions = '';
    $item->facebook->follow = '';

    $item->twitter->title = TW_TITLE;
    $item->twitter->innerStyle = '';
    $item->twitter->dimensions = '';
    $item->twitter->follow = '';

    $item->tumblr->title = TU_TITLE;
    $item->tumblr->innerStyle = '';
    $item->tumblr->dimensions = '';
    $item->tumblr->follow = '';

    $item->pinterest->title = PI_TITLE;
    $item->pinterest->innerStyle = '';
    $item->pinterest->dimensions = '';
    $item->pinterest->follow = '';

    return order_output($item);
}


//does the ordering of the output and returns the resultant string
function order_output($item) {
    $style_string = "position:relative;display:inline-block;width:25px;height:25px;
        overflow:hidden;margin-left:4px;vertical-align:top;border-radius:17px;
        background-image: url(\"/i/iSpr.png\");"; //TODO: make it an absolute path when we put it up
    $style = " style='$style_string;";
    $item->facebook->style = $style . "background-color:#3c5897;background-position:-28px 0px;'";
    $item->twitter->style = $style . "background-color:#2daae0;background-position:-55px 0px;'";
    $item->tumblr->style = $style . "background-color:#2a4361;background-position:-82px 0px;'";
    $item->pinterest->style = $style . "background-color:#ca1f25;background-position:-108px 0px;'";

    return  output_item($item->facebook) .
            output_item($item->twitter) .
            output_item($item->tumblr) .
            output_item($item->pinterest);
}

//its only responsibility is to accept an object to return the output html
function output_item($item) {
    ob_start();
?><div<?php echo $item->style?>><a target="_blank" title="<?php
        echo $item->title?>"<?php
        echo $item->innerStyle?> href="<?php
        echo $item->link
        ?>"<?php
        echo $item->follow?><?php
        echo $item->dimensions?>><?php
            echo $item->title?></a></div><?php
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: you should probably say what language you're working in

Comment: I'm working in PHP, which does have lambdas and closures. It also has kind of higher order functions where you pass the name of the function you want called by name. I was wondering if that's enough to have the proper level of abstraction or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't belive I got enough information to hit the nail on the head since you didn't say anything about the nature of A, B, C and D. However, if they are anything like sub classes and we want to perform some kind of operation on all of them that are inherited we have the `iam` function that treats them similar. The condition I don't know where came from so I added it as an argument and in the anonymous function index, which is derievd from condition, is's closed in from the scope of which the function is created.

```
function iam(item, index)
{
   return "I am " . item . index; // Might be more advanced than this
}   


function do_complicated_stuff(input, condition) {
    array_of_abcd = db_readabcd(input);

    index = (condition ? 1 : 2);
    handle = function(item)
             {
                 // function has index as free variable
                 return iam( item, index );
             }
    // Use map to iterate over the elelemts of the array
    // applying handle on each one       
    return map(handle array_of_abcd);
}
```

This example shows two properties of functional programming. Closures and higher order functions. Here is the same in Scheme:

```
(define (iam item index)
  (string-append "I am " 
                 item
                 index))

(define (do-complecated-stuff input condition)

  (let ([array-of-abcd (db-readabcd input)] ; get data
        [index (number->string (if condition 1 2))]) ; get index

    ; use map to iterate over elements with an anonymous function
    (map (lambda (item) (iam item index)) array-of-abcd)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the iam function would have around 13 parameters to it to do it this way because there are 16 different cases. Should I just paste the entire file in, it's like 200 lines of mind-numbing PHP code (which does have closures and lambdas and map(), though)?